# A phantom-like command that instead replaces the text with a horizontal line?

Tags: spacing, formatting

I'm trying to find a way of replacing part of text with a horizontal line.  I'd like it to behave like the phantom command which replaces the text with an empty box of the correct width (and height), but instead put a horizontal line through the box.

As a specific example, I'm seeking something like a `\phantomdash` command, where adding it to text in this manner

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \phantomdash{consectetuer adipiscing} elit...
```

would replace "consectetuer adipiscing" with a horizontal line of the width of the argument "consectetuer adipiscing".

*Question*:  Is there a command for this already?  If not, what is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`censor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/censor) can help in this regard:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/censor
\setlength{\censorruledepth}{.5ex}
\setlength{\censorruleheight}{.4pt}
\let\phantomdash\xblackout
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit\ldots

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \phantomdash{consectetuer adipiscing} elit\ldots

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eget pharetra nisi, at cursus orci. Fusce ipsum justo, \ldots

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \phantomdash{Suspendisse eget pharetra} nisi, at cursus orci. Fusce ipsum justo, \ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that (this worked for me).  And thanks for the other answers too!

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand\phantomdash[1]{%
    \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \phantomdash{consectetuer adipiscing} elit...
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can move the line up if you want so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand\phantomdash[1]{%
    \setlength\ULdepth{-0.5ex}
    \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \phantomdash{consectetuer adipiscing} elit...
\end{document}
```

Comment: When using this where spacing matters: comment out the newline after the `\ULdepth{-0.5ex}` command with a `%`. The original version puts a space before the phantom box, causing a slight misalignment when using this trick in e.g. tables.

Answer (score 6):

I write a lot of documents where I create blanks for answers on quizzes and then fill in the blanks for an answer key or solution sheet.  Here's the sort of approach I take to this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifhideanswers
\hideanswerstrue
\newlength\ae@tmp@length
\newcommand\phantomdash[1]{%%
  \ifhideanswers
    \settowidth\ae@tmp@length{#1}%%
    \rule[-0.25ex]{\ae@tmp@length}{0.4pt}%%
  \else
    #1%%
  \fi}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

What is the antipode of the north pole?  \phantomdash{the south pole}.

\hideanswersfalse
What is the antipode of the north pole?  \phantomdash{the south pole}.

\end{document}
```

> [image]

This approach works fairly well as long as you're not intending to underline long strings of text.  In particular, if you're not worried about the text to be hidden breaking across lines, then I find this to be a decent enough approach.  If you need the text to break across lines, then this approach is not so good.

Also, I don't like having to open and close file to rewrite just one line --- inevitably I accidentally delete or add something I don't want, particularly when I'm in a hurry.  So,
I usually do some kind of test on the existence of a an outside hidden file to determine whether the flag should be set.  For example I might have something along the following lines in my preamble:

```
 \IfFileExists{./.design/hide.answers.true}{\hideanswerstrue}{\hideanswersfalse}
```